# Apexcharts - Modelling multiple series (more than 2) with different y-axis scales

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

We've been trying to find a way to do this through Apexcharts.

We have multiple series with a shared x-axis (date), but different y-axis scales, which we're trying to normalize so we can show multiple data points together.

The only examples we can find for doing this have been supporting only 2 series at maximum:
https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/multiple-yaxis-scales/

[image: img]

Our series may have values like:

- [10,12,14,15,16]
- [0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.4]
- [131,127,150,129,144]

We cannot have these sharing the same y-axis as then the 2nd series would look very squished. Somehow, we're trying to find a way to visually display all these 3 on the same graph in a way that the individual differences are still visible.

So really what we're doing is we're "normalizing" the different y-axis ranges, while still preserving the exact original value.

We're open to alternatives other than Apexcharts too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to plot two series on the same yaxis scale?
if so here's a workaround [modelling multiple series with two y-axis](https://codepen.io/anass-ayar/pen/ZErqwGW)
otherwise, if you're just trying to plot as many axes as series, here's an example [modeling multiple series with an axis for each serie](https://codepen.io/anass-ayar/pen/bGLmzeX)

First example :

```
var options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: "Serie 1",
            type: "line",
            data: [10,12,14,15,16]
        },
        {
            name: "Serie 2",
            type: "line",
            data: [0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.4]
        },
        {
            name: "Serie 3",
            type: "line",
            data: [131,127,150,129,144]
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "line",
        stacked: false
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 2
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
    },
    yaxis: [
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 1",
            min:0,
            max:200,
            axisTicks: {
                show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#008FFB"
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#008FFB"]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Axe 1",
                style: {
                    color: "#008FFB"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 2",
            opposite: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            axisTicks: {
                show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#FEB019"
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#FEB019"]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Axe 2",
                style: {
                    color: "#FEB019"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 3",
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            axisTicks: {
                show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: false
            },
            labels: {
                show:false,
            },
            title: {
                text: "",
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    ],
    legend: {
        horizontalAlign: "left",
        offsetX: 40
    }
};
```

Second example :

```
var options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: "Serie 1",
            type: "line",
            data: [10,12,14,15,16]
        },
        {
            name: "Serie 2",
            type: "line",
            data: [0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.4]
        },
        {
            name: "Serie 3",
            type: "line",
            data: [131,127,150,129,144]
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "line",
        stacked: false
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 2
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
    },
    yaxis: [
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 1",
            axisTicks: {
                show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#008FFB"
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#008FFB"]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Axe 1",
                style: {
                    color: "#008FFB"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 2",
            opposite: true,
            axisTicks: {
                show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#FEB019"
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#FEB019"]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Axe 2",
                style: {
                    color: "#FEB019"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        {
            seriesName: "Serie 3",
            axisTicks: {
                show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#008FFB"
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#008FFB"]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Axe 3",
                style: {
                    color: "#008FFB"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
    ],
    legend: {
        horizontalAlign: "left",
        offsetX: 40
    }
};
```

Comment: Do any of you know how to avoid transparency in such multi-axis situations? With 5 series, 2 column, 3 line, i get very diluted colors.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you elaborate more? Maybe screenshots could help